# Leaflet disable vertical dragging out of bounds

Tags: leaflet

Is it possible to only have vertical bounds in leaflet to remove grey bands above and below the leaflet map?

[image: Grey bands around map]

I still want to keep horizontal wrap but just want to remove the grey areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use the minZoom option, and set it to 3, that's what I do ;)

```
this.map.setView(new L.LatLng(31.585692323629303, 35.19333585601518), 2);
    L.tileLayer(`https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`, {
      maxZoom: 20,
      minZoom: 3,
      attribution: 'HOT'
    }).addTo(this.map);
```

in my case using angular, hope it help